# C programming - unsigned int overflow problem

Tags: c, integer, int, overflow, unsigned

I want to print out an integer type variable which value is 3000000000;

So I wrote the below code then ran it, but the printed value was incorrect. I think the variable is overflowed. But I don't know why.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int num1 = 3000000000;

    printf("%d", num1);
}
```

As far as I know, **the maximum value of unsigned integer type variable is (2^32-1 = 4,294,967,296 - 1)** when the code complies on Win32 API.
**But the printed value is -1294967296.**

I have no idea why overflow occurs in my code.

If anyone knows the reason, please let me know :)

Best regards,

- I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional.

Comment: Try `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: `%d` is for signed `int`s. It will take whatever value it finds and interpret it as `signed int` and print it. Try `unsigned int num1 = 0xffffffff; printf("%d", num1);`. It will be more obvious. `4294967295` = `0xffffffff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `%u` not `%d`

For `printf`:

`%d` is used by:

> d, i The int argument is converted to signed decimal notation.The
>   precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that
>   must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it
>   is padded on the left with zeros.  The default precision is 1.
>   When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is
>   empty.

`%u` is used by:

> o, u, x, X
>                 The unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o),
>                 unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) nota‐
>                 tion.  The letters abcdef are used for x conversions; the let‐
>                 ters ABCDEF are used for X conversions.  The precision, if
>                 any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if
>                 the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the
>                 left with zeros.  The default precision is 1.  When 0 is
>                 printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty.

see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html